# How to use tabs for Markdown indentation in IntelliJ 2020.2.1

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown, indentation

For every file type it is possible to press the button at the end of the bottom bar and change to tabs in the popup but the popup for Markdown **does not show an option** to use tab character, even though the buttons says "Configure Indents".

How can I use tabs for Markdown without having to do "CTRL+SHIFT+A -> To Tabs" after every time I've finished writing?

[image: button]

[image: popup]

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot with mentioned button?

Comment: @y.bedrov Added.

Comment: What IDE version do you use?

Comment: 2020.2.1 (as in title) when I created the question but now it is 2020.2.2. Issue still present.

Comment: Am I got you right that you click on "4 spaces" and it suggests to switch to tabs? I see only "Configure Indents" for all file types.

Comment: I want tabs, it does not allow me to change. It is locked on 4 spaces.

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot with popup that suggests to switch between tabs and spaces?

Comment: Please re-read the question. I does **not** allow me to change, I want to change, but it doesn't let me do so.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Indents settings will be added in 2020.3 version.

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded early access and indeed, I can use tabs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in 2020.3 (currently early access).

Issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243531

Comment: Read https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243531 for more information

Comment: Thanks, I had read it but didn't think of writing it in the answer.

Comment: Yes, assumed that. I want to make it clear for all the other readers.